# How do I make diffmerge do a three-way merge with Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, diffmerge

I am currently using the commmand `hg diffmerge -r 32 -r 30 myfile`, but this only displays two windows, not three. How can I make it do a three way merge?

.hgrc

```
[ui]
merge=diffmerge

[extensions]
collapse=~/.hgext/collapse.py
hgext.purge=
hgext.extdiff=
hgext.graphlog=

[extdiff]
cmd.diffmerge=/usr/bin/diffmerge

[merge-tools]
diffmerge.executable=/usr/bin/diffmerge
diffmerge.args= --result=$output -t1="Local Version" -t2=$output -t3="Other Version" --caption=$output $local $base $other
diffmerge.binary=False
diffmerge.symlinks=False
diffmerge.gui=True
diffmerge.premerge=True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you mean you're using SourceGear DiffMerge as external merge tool. What's your `.hgrc`? Is it based on the [sample from hg website](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/DiffMerge)?

My guess is that your `diffmerge.args` is problematic. You can try running diffmerge manually with those arguments to make sure it works.

---

With your `.hgrc` it's clear now. Your command `hg diffmerge -r 32 -r 30 myfile` is NOT a merge command, instead you're asking hg to use diffmerge as the external diff tool (specified in `[extdiff]` section) to compare `myfile` between version 32 and 30. There's not a 3rd version involved.

For merge you run `hg merge [-r<the other head>]`, and since your `.hgrc` tells hg to use diffmerge as merge tool (specified in `[ui]` section) hg will use diffmerge for the 3-way merge. I verified that it works in my Windows setup with identical hgrc.